# PHP jQuery update sortable nested menu

Tags: php, jquery

I have a nested menu it is a menu with submenus. I am trying to make an interface with jquery sortable http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

You can sort the menu this works but I want to save the changes. My database looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------+------+
| item_id | parent_id | name |
+---------+-----------+------+
| 1       | 0         | Home |
+---------+-----------+------+
| 2       | 0         | Test |
+---------+-----------+------+
| 3       | 2         | Bla  |
+---------+-----------+------+
| 4       | 0         | Baa  |
+---------+-----------+------+
```

My sortable menu looks like

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Home</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="portlet">
<div class="portlet-header">Test</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
<div class="portlet-header">Bla</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="portlet">
<div class="portlet-header">Baa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like

```
$(function() {
  $( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    update: function() {
    }    

  });

  $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
    .find( ".portlet-header" )
    .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
    .end()
});
```

How can I found out what the new position is of the menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should show you the order. And store it in an array in the order where they are in the document.

```
var menu = new Array();
var order = 0;

$(".portlet-header").each(function(){
    menu.push($(this).html());
    alert(order + ":" + $(this).html());
    order += 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but when I put this in the update I get every alert twice, what do I need to change so he alert every menu item once in stead of twice?

Comment: Hmmm it shouldn't behave like that. Is the menu twice in the document? Could you create a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/